# add a counter in a multiple choices with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am currently developing an e-learning website with php 
I want to add a script to make a counter growing by 40 s for each question of a multiple choice.
that's what I did but it's just a simple counter that don't make any action after the time is left:

```
<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
<script>
var seconds = 4;
function secondPassed() {
var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
    remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
}
document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" +    remainingSeconds;
if (seconds == 0) {
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Buzz Buzz";


} else {    
    seconds--;
}
}
var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
</script>-->
```

if time passes then he goes on to the next question.

Comment: Off topic: Since Yahoo was closed, the world didn't use "Buzz" anymore...

Comment: Where are questions?? In an object or array or another url??

Answer (score 0):

Write a function which provide next question. If your next question is in other page, use `window.location.href = urlOfNextQuestion;` in `nextQuestion` function. If you have an array of questions and you have a counter for them, replace current question with new one.

```js
var seconds = 4;

function secondPassed() {
  var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30) / 60);
  var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
  if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
    remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
  }
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
  if (seconds == 0) {
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Buzz Buzz";
  nextQuestion();
  } else {
    seconds--;
  }
}
var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);

function nextQuestion() {
  // window.location.href = urlOfNextQuestion;
   alert("here we go");
  // You have an index of current and next question and show new question
}
```

```html
<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
```